# Is there a website where I can play against AI in the board game Abalone?

Tags: game-accessories, abalone

I'm looking for something like [this](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/abalone/id583042071?mt=8) except online and with AI I can play against. If it's free, that's even better.

Comment: I don't know about websites, but there is at least one Android-compatible app that has computer AI including a series of progressively more difficult challenges.

Comment: Do you happen to know the name of it or have a link to it in the play store?

Comment: I use one called Abalone from the Google Play Store.  The developer is SPPA4APPS.  I got the paid version, but they also have a free version "Abalone Free" with many of the same features.  There are fewer challenge levels, but it will let you see if you like the implementation before buying it.

Comment: I know, the UI and design is not as in example, but maybe someone else would be interested: http://playdosgamesonline.com/abalone.html (Has 6 levels)